# Assignment Operator Overloading in C++ Syntax Explanation

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, this

I am new to C++. I need some help understanding this code snippet.

```
Queue & operator=(const Queue &rhs)
{
    front = rhs.front;
    nWaiting = rhs.nWaiting;
    for (int i = front, j = 0; j < nWaiting; j++) 
    {
        elements[i] = rhs.elements[i];
        i = (i + 1) % 100;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I am unable to understand why there is an '&' before operator in the code and how does this work along with *this.

I understand operator overloading. For eg. the code below for addition operation overloading. However I don't understand why '&' is required for assignment operator (=) overloading.

```
V3 operator* (const double factor, const V3 &b)
{
    return (b * factor);
}
```

Comment: The & means that the return type of the function is a reference to a Queue.

Comment: Queue& returns a reference to the same object, rather than a copy. The intention is for the `=` operation to mutate the original object and return a reference to itself.

Comment: Note the `&` tokens in this code are not called operators.  The operator `&` gets the address of an object.  But this is an entirely different meaning of `&` used in declarations and other places where you specify a type.  Writing `&` after a type names another type which is a reference to the type just named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference means that avoid *copying* the object. As a result, it will return a reference to the *same object*. Moreover, it will provide ***lvalue*** as a result. And if you think about it, that's what you want to happen when the assignment operator is used.

Every object in C++ has access to its own address through `this` pointer.

That means that the you return the object itself.

If your question is why we use `*this` instead of `this`, then this happens because you need to *dereference* the pointer first, since the return type is a reference (and not a pointer for example).

Comment: In this context reference is not to avoid copying but to provide `lvalue` as a result

Comment: @Slava it achieves both purposes

Comment: @Slava I should add that too, thank you! Did the answer improve now? I agree with M.M.

Comment: @M.M I doubt it, lets say object is very small and it would be more efficient to pass it by value rather than reference, should `operator=` return non reference then?

Answer (score 3):

The `&` means the operator returns a reference (the original object), instead of a value (a copy of the object). This avoids unnecessary copying. `this` is a pointer to the object itself which the operator is called on, so `return *this` means return a reference to the object on the left side of the `=`.

This allows for the operator to be chained, like `a = b = 1`. This assigns 1 to `b` first, and a reference to `b` is returned. The value of `b` then gets assigned to `a`. So `a` and `b` both are 1.

Answer (score 0):

The operator could be fine without any return value, however it is common to enable chaining as in

```
c = (a = b);
```

This will assign `b` to `a` and then assign the return value of the `operator=` call to `c`. As you dont want to make a unneccesary copy you return a reference to the object itself aka `*this`. Actually avoiding a copy is not the only reason for using a reference, but if you consider

```
(d = e) = f;
```

then this will only work as expected (first assigning `e` to `d` and then assigning `f` to `d`) if `operator=` returns a non-const (!) reference.

Note that `operator*` is different, because it is not supposed to modify the object it is invoked on but rather it returns a new instance (hence no `&` in the return of `operator*`).

Comment: "As you dont want to make a unneccesary copy" if that the case the const reference should be used

Comment: @Slava hm? with a const ref this would not work: `(a = b) = c;`. Not sure what copy you are refering to

Comment: I provided quote to your answer, and if your explanation is correct and reference is used to avoid unneccesary copy then const refernece should be used. If there is another reason, for example to make `(a = b) = c;` work then your explanation is wrong.

Comment: @Slava how does a const ref prohibit a copy more than a non-const ref?

Comment: Prohibit copy more? Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Slava if `operator=` would return `Queue` then the return value would be a copy. If the return is `Queue&` then the return value is not a copy. This is the unneccesary copy I was refering to in my answer and I dont get why you think it would have to be a const reference to avoid that copy

Comment: When you pass function parameter by value you make a copy, when you want to avoid copy you pass it as **const reference** The same story here. Reference in this case is not used to avoid copy but to provide lvalue.

Comment: @Slava as I understood the question it is about the return type of the operator, not the parameter type, is this the misunderstanding?

Comment: @Slava "when you want to avoid copy you pass it as const reference " sorry i still dont get why you insist on const. If you pass a function parameter and you dont want to copy, then you pass a reference, wether it is const or not is secondary

Comment: When you want to avoid copy you pass const reference, when you want function to modify parameter you pass non const reference, if you do not understand basic principles you should avoid providing answers to others.

Comment: @Slava the question is not about passing parameters to a function or at least thats not what my answer is about. There is no copy for the return value of the `operator=` whether the return value is `const` or not. The only way I can understand your critizism is that it is about nitpicking about wording. I would be glad to see a better phrasing by you, but I dont see how your comments contribute anything to improving my answer

Comment: It is not nitpicking. Question: if there is a small object which is more efficient to pass/return by value can I return by value for `operator=`? If not then your reasoning why reference is choosen here is plain wrong.

Comment: @Slava happy now?

Comment: No, avoiding copy not a reason here at all - you need to return non-const reference, if you want to avoid copy or do not want that is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @Slava come on. I even included a comparison to `operator*` where the return value is a copy. I understand that not copying is not the only reason for using a reference, but calling it wrong or irrelevant or telling me not to write answer because of my incompetence for that reason is pure exaggeration imho. I can live with your downvote

Comment: Again, you do not have choice in this case to avoid copy or not, how that could be a reason? Can you say I got driver license because it saves room in my wallet as it more compact than passport and as "side effect" it let me drive a car?

Comment: @Slava `operator=` could return a value rather than a refence, but thats not how it is supposed to work

Comment: @Slava better analogy would be: I say "I have a drivers license so I can drive to work" and you say "no thats irrelevant and wrong, because you could take the bus"

Comment: Are you familiar with logic? If you say reason for this action is that, it means you remove reason and action would be not necessary. I am asking again, if I do not need to avoid copy will that remove necessity of using reference here?